# WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name null after deploying to IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an MVC 4 app which run fine locally, however, after deploying to IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 the code can't retrieve the current user from AD. 
That returns null and i get a NullReferenceException.

I have changed from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService severally, enabled Windows Authentication in the project settings, gave permission in folder settings to IIS_IUSRS but none worked for me.

This is expected to be deployed as an intranet solution so it should leave on one of the intranet servers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Try disabling anonymous authentication
- Double check that Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS [see here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [especially here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication?showTreeNavigation=true)
- Check impersonate in web.config - [some more on that](https://forums.asp.net/t/1507047.aspx?WindowsIdentity%20GetCurrent%20Name%20vs%20User%20Identity%20Name)

Comment: I found out Windows Authentication was not activated in Server Manager and then i did activated it. But it does not seem to work yet

Comment: did you disable anonymous authentication? you might also need to update your web.config. I updated my answer to show that windowsitentity.getcurrent.name is often not the actual AD user that opens the site

Comment: I disabled Anonymous authentication but didn't work. I tired impersonation earlier and I found out every user accessing it on the domain was actually seeing my profile which was weird. So i disabled it.
That link you shared however got me confused, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() should give me current user, however I already used `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name` and it still didn't work